# Redirect user from iOS browser to App if installed, or to App Store if not - like Yelp

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links

How can I detect whether the user browsing to my website has installed my app, and redirect to it on the click of a button in the banner like yelp?

I only need help with the detecting and redirecting from the browser. Yelp manages to do it. I tried messing with universal links, but I'm not sure how to detect that the user does not have the app and to then redirect him/her to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Yelp uses a company called [Branch](http://branch.io) (Full disclosure, I work there). We have some complicated infrastructure that allows us to tell when a particular device has the app installed or not.